# Interpretation of SEM - prediction

Tags: r, pca, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am trying to model a behavior using the Theory of Planned Behavior (TPB) as my main framework.
I have an active survey; currently with 110 answers. I'm using R with lavaan to run the following model.

```
sem_factors_4 <- '
  Att_x       =~ ATT_good       + ATT_important + self_1 + self_2 + ATT_useful
  PBC_x       =~ PBC_time       + PBC_space + ATT_pleasant + ATT_hygenic
  Soc_x       =~ MN_friend      + MN_colleg + MN_family + MN_media 
  Intention   ~ Att_x + PBC_x + Soc_x
  Beh_avg     ~ Intention + PBC_x'
```

Then I fit the model `fit.factors_4 <- sem(sem_factors_4, data=data_corr, std.lv = TRUE, estimator = "MLM")` and do a summary of the results:

```
lavaan 0.6-12 ended normally after 44 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        36

  Number of observations                           110

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Robust
  Test Statistic                               145.057     117.862
  Degrees of freedom                                84          84
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.009
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.231
    Satorra-Bentler correction                                    

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                           Robust.sem
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Att_x =~                                            
    ATT_good          0.493    0.127    3.899    0.000
    ATT_important     0.514    0.124    4.135    0.000
    self_1            0.352    0.157    2.237    0.025
    self_2            0.396    0.118    3.358    0.001
    ATT_useful       -0.330    0.048   -6.879    0.000
  PBC_x =~                                            
    PBC_time          0.647    0.089    7.258    0.000
    PBC_space         0.725    0.096    7.526    0.000
    ATT_pleasant      0.417    0.102    4.095    0.000
    ATT_hygenic      -0.419    0.109   -3.833    0.000
  Soc_x =~                                            
    MN_friend         1.037    0.074   14.104    0.000
    MN_colleg         1.000    0.086   11.691    0.000
    MN_family         0.770    0.106    7.258    0.000
    MN_media          0.642    0.095    6.747    0.000

Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Intention ~                                         
    Att_x             0.069    0.052    1.327    0.185
    PBC_x             0.178    0.071    2.493    0.013
    Soc_x             0.138    0.093    1.475    0.140
  Beh_avg ~                                           
    Intention         4.108    2.710    1.516    0.130
    PBC_x             3.645    1.912    1.907    0.057

Covariances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Att_x ~~                                            
    PBC_x             0.322    0.117    2.748    0.006
    Soc_x            -0.038    0.070   -0.551    0.582
  PBC_x ~~                                            
    Soc_x            -0.064    0.099   -0.646    0.518

Variances:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .ATT_good          0.089    0.029    3.049    0.002
   .ATT_important     0.141    0.039    3.626    0.000
   .self_1            0.412    0.125    3.284    0.001
   .self_2            0.529    0.106    5.008    0.000
   .ATT_useful        0.331    0.137    2.426    0.015
   .PBC_time          0.246    0.088    2.807    0.005
   .PBC_space         0.722    0.124    5.807    0.000
   .ATT_pleasant      0.668    0.109    6.114    0.000
   .ATT_hygenic       0.980    0.151    6.474    0.000
   .MN_friend         0.147    0.073    2.014    0.044
   .MN_colleg         0.394    0.126    3.120    0.002
   .MN_family         0.938    0.155    6.044    0.000
   .MN_media          0.746    0.126    5.909    0.000
   .Intention         0.461    0.157    2.944    0.003
   .Beh_avg         194.233   36.596    5.308    0.000
    Att_x             1.000                           
    PBC_x             1.000                           
    Soc_x             1.000
```

From this summary i can see that Intention has a coef of 4.108 and is not stat. sig (0.130) and that PBC_x has a value of 3.645 and is stat. sig (0.057).

But when I run the following summary i get different results in coefficients and p-vals

```
standardizedsolution(fit.factors_4, type = "std.all", se = TRUE, zstat = TRUE, pvalue = TRUE, ci = TRUE) %>% 
  filter(op == "~") %>% 
  select(LV=lhs, Item=rhs, Coefficient=est.std, ci.lower,ci.upper, SE=se, Z=z, 'p-value'=pvalue)
```

Console print from `standardizedsolution()`

```
         LV      Item Coefficient ci.lower ci.upper    SE     Z p.value
1 Intention     Att_x       0.096   -0.046    0.238 0.072 1.330   0.184
2 Intention     PBC_x       0.247    0.003    0.491 0.124 1.984   0.047
3 Intention     Soc_x       0.191   -0.014    0.395 0.104 1.824   0.068
4   Beh_avg Intention       0.199   -0.003    0.401 0.103 1.930   0.054
5   Beh_avg     PBC_x       0.245   -0.013    0.502 0.131 1.861   0.063
```

How can i use this results to make predictions (yhat)?
I need to make a simulation based on this results, how can get an explicit equation from this results?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Best
Jonathan

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Sure! MrBot, ill edit it. Thanks!

Comment: What sort of simulation do you want to do? Why do you care about the standardized solution for the simulation?

Comment: Thanks @JeremyMiles! The project has two steps, first I run this model to extract coefficients. Then this coefficients are inputs of an Agent-Based simulation (ABM). This means that in my case the factors PBC, Attitude and Social Norms will be changing, therefore I need to evaluate the equation to generate new values of behavior. I hope this helps to clarify