# Equation of model to predict latent and observed variables

Tags: r, least-squares, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I'm struggling to interpret my SEM results and extract the "regression equation" that generates yhat. Using lavaan in R, this is my model that I want to estimate.

```
sem_tpb <- '
  # Latents
  Att_x         =~ ATT_good_100       + ATT_important_100 + self_1_100 + self_2_100 + ATT_useful_100
  PBC_x         =~ PBC_time_100       + PBC_space_100 + ATT_pleasant_100 + ATT_hygenic_100
  Soc_x         =~ MN_friend_25_100      + MN_colleg_25_100 + MN_family_25_100 + MN_media_25_100
  
  # Regressions
  Intention_100         ~ Att_x       + PBC_x + Soc_x
  beh_avg               ~ Intention_100       + PBC_x + dist_pak'
```

Then I run the model and some diagnosis...

```
fit.factors <- sem(sem_tpb, data=TPB_reg, 
                   std.lv = TRUE, estimator = "MLM")

summary(fit.factors)

fitMeasures(fit.factors, chi)
fitMeasures(fit.factors, more_test)
fitMeasures(fit.factors, extra_test)
```

The model produces the following outputs:

```
lavaan 0.6-12 ended normally after 77 iterations

  Estimator                                         ML
  Optimization method                           NLMINB
  Number of model parameters                        37

                                                  Used       Total
  Number of observations                           103         110

Model Test User Model:
                                              Standard      Robust
  Test Statistic                               150.273     126.800
  Degrees of freedom                                98          98
  P-value (Chi-square)                           0.001       0.027
  Scaling correction factor                                  1.185
    Satorra-Bentler correction                                    

Parameter Estimates:

  Standard errors                           Robust.sem
  Information                                 Expected
  Information saturated (h1) model          Structured

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate    Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Att_x =~                                              
    ATT_good_100       12.629    3.282    3.848    0.000
    ATT_mprtnt_100     13.006    3.243    4.011    0.000
    self_1_100          9.005    4.087    2.203    0.028
    self_2_100         10.323    3.023    3.415    0.001
    ATT_useful_100     -8.376    1.234   -6.790    0.000
  PBC_x =~                                              
    PBC_time_100       20.713    2.938    7.049    0.000
    PBC_space_100      17.922    2.561    6.997    0.000
    ATT_plesnt_100      9.775    2.584    3.783    0.000
    ATT_hygenc_100    -10.994    2.831   -3.884    0.000
  Soc_x =~                                              
    MN_frnd_25_100     26.309    1.930   13.633    0.000
    MN_cllg_25_100     25.437    2.215   11.484    0.000
    MN_fmly_25_100     20.128    2.732    7.367    0.000
    MN_medi_25_100     16.055    2.466    6.509    0.000

Regressions:
                   Estimate    Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Intention_100 ~                                       
    Att_x               1.677    1.378    1.217    0.223
    PBC_x               4.554    1.948    2.338    0.019
    Soc_x               3.668    2.447    1.499    0.134
  beh_avg ~                                             
    Intention_100       0.102    0.084    1.220    0.222
    PBC_x               5.518    1.605    3.437    0.001
    dist_pak            0.008    0.003    3.049    0.002

Covariances:
                   Estimate    Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Att_x ~~                                              
    PBC_x               0.341    0.116    2.938    0.003
    Soc_x              -0.062    0.071   -0.872    0.383
  PBC_x ~~                                              
    Soc_x              -0.070    0.106   -0.660    0.509

Variances:
                   Estimate    Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
   .ATT_good_100       53.542   18.096    2.959    0.003
   .ATT_mprtnt_100     94.289   25.428    3.708    0.000
   .self_1_100        266.850   83.179    3.208    0.001
   .self_2_100        326.561   70.646    4.623    0.000
   .ATT_useful_100    214.272   90.559    2.366    0.018
   .PBC_time_100      285.269   91.498    3.118    0.002
   .PBC_space_100     440.050   80.524    5.465    0.000
   .ATT_plesnt_100    437.482   70.376    6.216    0.000
   .ATT_hygenc_100    622.601  101.132    6.156    0.000
   .MN_frnd_25_100    101.616   47.807    2.126    0.034
   .MN_cllg_25_100    253.376   82.672    3.065    0.002
   .MN_fmly_25_100    586.954  103.452    5.674    0.000
   .MN_medi_25_100    468.148   82.309    5.688    0.000
   .Intention_100     297.981  104.133    2.862    0.004
   .beh_avg           156.337   25.470    6.138    0.000
    Att_x               1.000                           
    PBC_x               1.000                           
    Soc_x               1.000                           

> fitMeasures(fit.factors, chi)
 chisq.scaled     df.scaled pvalue.scaled 
      126.800        98.000         0.027 
> fitMeasures(fit.factors, more_test)
         rmsea.scaled rmsea.ci.lower.scaled rmsea.ci.upper.scaled   rmsea.pvalue.scaled 
                0.053                 0.023                 0.076                 0.396 
> fitMeasures(fit.factors, extra_test)
cfi.scaled       srmr 
     0.898      0.086
```

I want to get the coefficients that describe beh_avg, so i tried

```
standardizedsolution(fit.factors, type = "std.all", se = TRUE, zstat = TRUE, 
pvalue = TRUE, ci = TRUE) %>%  filter(op == "~") %>%  select(LV=lhs, Item=rhs, Coefficient=est.std, ci.lower,  ci.upper, SE=se, Z=z, 'p-value'=pvalue)

             LV          Item Coefficient ci.lower ci.upper    SE     Z p.value
1 Intention_100         Att_x       0.091   -0.054    0.237 0.074 1.233   0.218
2 Intention_100         PBC_x       0.248   -0.012    0.508 0.133 1.870   0.061
3 Intention_100         Soc_x       0.200   -0.009    0.408 0.106 1.879   0.060
4       beh_avg Intention_100       0.132   -0.048    0.312 0.092 1.439   0.150
5       beh_avg         PBC_x       0.387    0.178    0.597 0.107 3.628   0.000
6       beh_avg      dist_pak       0.185    0.072    0.298 0.058 3.218   0.001
```

-->> So my question is, how do I can extract the equation that describe beh_avg?
I have also tried using blavPredict with bcfa and with some warnings im able to get latent variables, but when i specify "yhat", it gives me the following error:

```
Error in do.call("rbind", x)[cids, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

An alternative (that i dont know if it is equivalent), but i tried is to create the LV from CFA
but the R2 is very low for intention and behaviour... any suggestions?

For Intention

```
> lm_int = lm(Intention_100 ~ Attitude_100 + PBC_100 + Social_norm_100,
+             data = TPB_reg)
> summary(lm_int)

Call:
lm(formula = Intention_100 ~ Attitude_100 + PBC_100 + Social_norm_100, 
    data = TPB_reg)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-86.998  -8.430   5.389  11.050  20.062 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     49.52511   13.05319   3.794 0.000247 ***
Attitude_100     0.27056    0.13965   1.937 0.055359 .  
PBC_100          0.16633    0.07759   2.144 0.034330 *  
Social_norm_100  0.14623    0.06896   2.121 0.036290 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 17.35 on 106 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1091,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.08384 
F-statistic: 4.325 on 3 and 106 DF,  p-value: 0.00643
```

And then, for behavior...

```
> lm_beh = lm(beh_avg ~ Intention_100 + PBC_100 + dist_pak,
+             data = TPB_reg)
> summary(lm_beh)

Call:
lm(formula = beh_avg ~ Intention_100 + PBC_100 + dist_pak, data = TPB_reg)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-38.832  -4.986   3.742   8.671  24.710 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   60.416677   6.951925   8.691 7.78e-14 ***
Intention_100  0.149532   0.074733   2.001   0.0481 *  
PBC_100        0.145466   0.065400   2.224   0.0284 *  
dist_pak       0.007700   0.004275   1.801   0.0747 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 13.51 on 99 degrees of freedom
  (7 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.1282,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1018 
F-statistic: 4.854 on 3 and 99 DF,  p-value: 0.003417
```

Comment: This is follow-up - update of the non responded:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/600109/interpretation-of-sem-prediction?noredirect=1#comment1111782_600109

Comment: What do you mean by "extract the equation"?  The slopes are listed in the `parameterEstimates()` or `summary()` output under the "Regressions" heading.  If you don't want to pretend your data are mean-centered, then add `meanstructure=TRUE` to your `sem()` call and you will see an "Intercepts" section listed in the output that includes slopes, (residual) variances, etc.  If you are looking for a particular format, or want to create a particular R object, please create something from your `lm()` results to show what you want from `lavaan`.